# php foreach array data structure

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hello I need help please. I am a student and I have a problem with php.

I have this data structure:

```
array
[0] => array(3){
        ["type"]=>"fruits"
        ["name"]=>"banane"
        ["depends"]=>array(3){
                      [0]=>"fraise"
                      [1]=>"kiwi"
                      [2]=>"pomme"  
                      }
        }
[1] => array(3){
        ["type"]=>"fruits"
        ["name"]=>"ananas"
        ["depends"]=>array(3){
                      [0]=>"avocat"
                      [1]=>"kiwi"
                      [2]=>"banane"  
                      }
        } 
[2] => array(3){
        ["type"]=>"fruits"
        ["name"]=>"kiwi"
        ["depends"]=>array(3){
                      [0]=>"ananas"
                      [1]=>"avocat"
                      [2]=>"banane"  
                      }
                } 
  ...
```

---

First I need to have a name array like this:

```
  array {
      [0]=>"banane"
      [1]=>"ananas"
      ...
  }
```

---

For each array name I am looking to have:
//first foreach look if name existe in depends and do

```
  array {
      ["banane"] =>array{
                    [0]=>"ananas"  
                    [1]=>"kiwi" 
      } 
      ["ananas"] =>array{
                    [0]=>"kiwi"  
      }         
  }
```

---

For my second foreach use each son of the first name. Look if name exists in `depends` and do:

```
array {
    ["banane"] =>array{
                  [0]=>"ananas" =>array{
                                        [0]=>"kiwi" 
                                        } 
                  [1]=>"kiwi" =>array{
                                      [0]=>"banane"
                                      [1]=>"ananas"
                                      }
    } 

    ["ananas"] =>array{
                  [0]=>"kiwi"  
    }         
}
```

---

and this is my code to do this

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("data/data.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

//create my liste of fruits
$fruits_liste = array_column($data, 'name');
$parcours = array();

foreach ($fruits_liste as $indice => $fruits_name) {
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($fruits_name, $value['depends'])) {
        $parcours[$fruits_name] = $value['name'];
    }
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($parcours);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

the result of my var_dump

```
array(3) {
  ["banane"]=>
  string(4) "kiwi"
  ["ananas"]=>
  string(4) "kiwi"
  ["kiwi"]=>
  string(6) "ananas"
}
```

---

my data file

```
[
    {
        "type"    : "fruits",
        "name"    : "banane",
        "depends" : [
            "fraise",
            "kiwi",
            "pomme"
        ]
    }, {
        "type"    : "fruits",
        "name"    : "ananas",
        "depends" : [
            "avocat",
            "kiwi",
            "banane"
        ]
    }, {
        "type"    : "fruits",
        "name"    : "kiwi",
        "depends" : [
            "ananas",
            "avocat",
            "banane"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working.

Comment: Where is your code or banana?

Comment: People here __do not__ write code for you. Read [mcve] and [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: The first requirement can be easily accomplished using the PHP function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). For the rest, use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and/or other [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).